How can I keep my mac from going to sleep while USB ports are in use?
Desire:  Mac goes to sleep after X minutes of inactivity.
Present behaviour:  If I am playing on my midi keyboard, connected by USB to my compter, mac will go to sleep.
How can I get it to stay awake while I'm practicing?

This could probably be done with a LaunchAgent that polls your USB device list and issues a caffeinate command to keep the Mac from sleeping if your MIDI keyboard is detected. If you're comfortable with Terminal, try installing jq to parse the JSON and then run system_profiler SPUSBDataType -json | jq -r '.SPUSBDataType[] | .. | ._name?' — is your keyboard listed there?

Let's not over-engineer a solution.  Start caffeinate yourself from a terminal, and end it when you are done practicing.  Or install something like Amphetamine to do the same thing.
